# printing issue: single page on PC is printing across multiple pages

Tags: ubuntu, printing, cups

I have just setup a ubuntu 11.10 desktop and i have an issue with the printing.

When I send a document from the desktop to the HP Officejet 6500 E710n-z it will center it and print across 4 pages.

```
-------------
|      |     |
|      |     |
|     A|B    |
|------|-----|
|     C|D    |
|      |     |
|      |     |
--------------
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: this to me seems like it's a simple configuration setting. Try print preview and see what it wants to print it as.. check your margins and padding and make sure it's not a grotesque amount - make sure the paper size is selected properly. And finally make sure your driver is in fact supported on 11.10

Answer (score 3):

I have fixed this issue, I found that the cups server I had pointed the client to was distributing the wrong driver.

I changed the client to point at the printer's built-in server and the problem was fixed.